# Firefox Add-on SDK getting the tab ID

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build a Firefox Add-on using the SDK (version 1.6), but I'm running into an issue with Tabs that the extension is opening.

I would like to obtain the tab that the `aContext` (node) is on.  To do so, I've been 'getting' the node's window, then using the Tab Utils in the SDK, specifically `getTabForContentWindow()`.  This sometimes doesn't work, the Tab returned from `getTabForContentWindow()` is null.  Is there a better, more robust method to get a node's Tab?

Also, I noticed on [the Tab Utils page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/tabs_utils), that it states it's 'unstable'.  Should I avoid using Tab Utils SDK?

Below is the code from the main.js:

```
const {Cc, Ci, Cr, Cu, Cm, components} = require("chrome");
const { XPCOMUtils } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm");
var winUtils = require('sdk/window/utils');
var tabUtils = require('sdk/tabs/utils');

let policy =
{
    classDescription: "my content policy",
    classID: components.ID("{2DA54ECA-FBDD-11E3-B3B1-695C1D5D46B0}"),
    contractID: "@www.com/policy;1",
    xpcom_categories: ["content-policy"],

    init: function()
    {
        let registrar = Cm.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIComponentRegistrar);
        registrar.registerFactory(this.classID, this.classDescription, this.contractID, this);

        let catMan = Cc["@mozilla.org/categorymanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICategoryManager);
        for each (let category in this.xpcom_categories)
            catMan.addCategoryEntry(category, this.contractID, this.contractID, false, true);
    },

    // nsIContentPolicy interface implementation
    shouldLoad: function(aContentType, aContentLocation, aRequestOrigin, aContext, aMimeTypeGuess, aExtra, aRequestPrincipal) {

        console.log("*****");
        console.log("aContentLocation.spec [" + aContentLocation.spec + "] ");
        console.log("aContentType [" + aContentType + "] ");
        if (aContext instanceof components.interfaces.nsIDOMNode) {            
            var node = aContext.QueryInterface(components.interfaces.nsIDOMNode);
            var win = getWindow(node);
            if (win) {
                console.log("window found" );
                var selectedTab = tabUtils.getTabForContentWindow(win);                
                if (selectedTab) {
                    console.log("tab found" );
                    var tabId = tabUtils.getTabId(selectedTab);
                    console.log("Node's tabId:" + tabId);
                } else {
                    console.log("tab undefined" );
                }
            } else {
                console.log("win undefined" );
            } 
        }
        return Ci.nsIContentPolicy.ACCEPT;

    },

    shouldProcess: function(contentType, contentLocation, requestOrigin, node, mimeTypeGuess, extra) {
        return Ci.nsIContentPolicy.ACCEPT;
    },

    // nsIFactory interface implementation
    createInstance: function(outer, iid) {
        if (outer)
            throw Cr.NS_ERROR_NO_AGGREGATION;
        return this.QueryInterface(iid);
    },

    // nsISupports interface implementation
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIContentPolicy, Ci.nsIFactory])
};

policy.init();

var scheduleCheckFilterUpdates = function() {
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    tabs.open("http://wikipedia.org");
}
require('sdk/timers').setTimeout(scheduleCheckFilterUpdates, 1000);

function getWindow(node) {
    if ("ownerDocument" in node && node.ownerDocument)
        node = node.ownerDocument;

    if ("defaultView" in node)
        return node.defaultView;

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that:

- Not all requests originate from a window. (background requests)
- Not all requests that originate from a window actually originate from a tab. When you run your code you can see e.g. requests for stuff like `chrome://browser/skin/tabbrowser/tab-separator.png` that the browser window itself loads (in this case to be used in the UI). Also keep in mind that not all top-level windows are actually browser windows (`browser.xul`).
- Even if it is a tab navigation, then **the initial load** (`aContentLocation.spec [http://wikipedia.org/]`) will originate from the new, not fully initialized content window that is being constructed, which **is not yet associated with any tab**. The tab at this point is still `about:blank` and the new window (`wikipedia`) will only be swapped in once it is clear that this window can be fully constructed: request wasn't blocked, DNS was resolved, redirects followed and the final response actually produced data and that data can be made into a window. E.g. if my network was down, the `wikipedia` window would be abandoned before ever being assigned to the tab and instead a connection error document and window would be created.

The last point is also *kinda* documented in [the `nsIContentPolicy` interface](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/464bca437658/content/base/public/nsIContentPolicy.idl) itself:

```
 /**
   * Should the resource at this location be loaded?
   * ShouldLoad will be called before loading the resource at aContentLocation
   * to determine whether to start the load at all.
   *
   * @param aContentType      the type of content being tested. This will be one
   *                          one of the TYPE_* constants.
   *
   * @param aContentLocation  the location of the content being checked; must
   *                          not be null
   *
   * @param aRequestOrigin    OPTIONAL. the location of the resource that
   *                          initiated this load request; can be null if
   *                          inapplicable
   *
   * @param aContext          OPTIONAL. the nsIDOMNode or nsIDOMWindow that
   *                          initiated the request, or something that can QI
   *                          to one of those; can be null if inapplicable.
   *                          Note that for navigation events (new windows and
   *                          link clicks), this is the NEW window.
   *
   * @param aMimeTypeGuess    OPTIONAL. a guess for the requested content's
   *                          MIME type, based on information available to
   *                          the request initiator (e.g., an OBJECT's type
   *                          attribute); does not reliably reflect the
   *                          actual MIME type of the requested content
   *
   * @param aExtra            an OPTIONAL argument, pass-through for non-Gecko
   *                          callers to pass extra data to callees.
   *
   * @param aRequestPrincipal an OPTIONAL argument, defines the principal that
   *                          caused the load. This is optional only for
   *                          non-gecko code: all gecko code should set this
   *                          argument.  For navigation events, this is
   *                          the principal of the page that caused this load.
   *
   * @return ACCEPT or REJECT_*
   *
   * @note shouldLoad can be called while the DOM and layout of the document
   * involved is in an inconsistent state.  This means that implementors of
   * this method MUST NOT do any of the following:
   * 1)  Modify the DOM in any way (e.g. setting attributes is a no-no).
   * 2)  Query any DOM properties that depend on layout (e.g. offset*
   *     properties).
   * 3)  Query any DOM properties that depend on style (e.g. computed style).
   * 4)  Query any DOM properties that depend on the current state of the DOM
   *     outside the "context" node (e.g. lengths of node lists).
   * 5)  [JavaScript implementations only] Access properties of any sort on any
   *     object without using XPCNativeWrapper (either explicitly or
   *     implicitly).  Due to various DOM0 things, this leads to item 4.
   * If you do any of these things in your shouldLoad implementation, expect
   * unpredictable behavior, possibly including crashes, content not showing
   * up, content showing up doubled, etc.  If you need to do any of the things
   * above, do them off timeout or event.
   */
  short shouldLoad(in nsContentPolicyType aContentType,
                   in nsIURI        aContentLocation,
                   in nsIURI        aRequestOrigin,
                   in nsISupports   aContext,
                   in ACString      aMimeTypeGuess,
                   in nsISupports   aExtra,
                   [optional] in nsIPrincipal  aRequestPrincipal);
```

### Conclusion

The Tab Utils work as expected as far as I can tell, and so does the code from @Notidart's answer. It is the expectation that a new document is immediately assigned to a tab that is wrong.

> Also, I noticed on the Tab Utils page, that it states it's 'unstable'. Should I avoid using Tab Utils SDK?

Well, that is up to your personal taste. *unstable* essentially means that the API can change again or even be removed again in a later version of the browser. The alternatives, like using `window.gBrowser` are at least as *unstable* as the SDK API (also can change at any point), so IMHO there is nothing to be gained from avoiding this SDK API, provided it doesn't turned out to be buggy in some way (but if it does, you can still switch to something else).

Comment: Dam I just can't compete. Bookmaring gosh man such good stuff.

Comment: The third bullet item above (about the tab not being completely initialized) , is what I thought might be occurring.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you can try. From the content window you get the dom window. Then with the dom window you do the getTabForContentWindow:

```
//var node = focused element?
var contentWin = node.ownerDocument.defaultView;
var DOMWin = contentWin.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
    .rootTreeItem
    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);
if (DOMWin.gBrowser && DOMWin.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
    var tab = DOMWin.gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contentWin);
} else {
    //the node is in a firefox window with no tabs
}
```

Its possible for it to be a poup window with no tabs.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the tab returned on the line:    
    
    var tab = DOMWin.gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(contentWin);  
    
is null for the initial document.  This is same behaviour I'm seeing with my original code.

Comment: What's "initial document"? I want to reproduce to test it out.