# Firefox addon - how to close tabs after opening them?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

In a javascript Firefox addon, please how can I keep an array of pointers to tabs the addon opens?
Ultimately I want to be able to process the DOM on each tab and then close the tab afterwards.

I've been looking at the MDN reference, but I can't get a clear picture in my head of the object model.

The addon opens a number of URLs in tabs.
The DOMContentLoaded event pushes the "tabs" into an array.
Later I process each "tab" in the array and do some stuff with it's DOM.
Then I want to close the tab.

In the code snippets below, it all seems to work except closing the tab.

Questions:

- In DOMloadedFunction, what type of object exactly is "event.target" ?
- In DOMloadedFunction, how can I keep some kind of "handle" to each
  new tab so I can close it later?

Code snippets:

```
var arrPages = [];

//Open the tab
newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.addTab(inURL));
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DOMloadedFunction, true);

// DOMContentLoaded eventhandler
DOMloadedFunction : function (event)
{
    // store the tab
    arrPages.push(event.target);
}

// Later the array is processed...
oPage = arrPages.shift();
oPage.contentDocument  <-- Do some stuff with DOM object.

// Now close the tab
oPage.close()    // this is what I want to do, but I can't figure out how

// Unfortunately the index for gBrowser.mTabs[] seems to change, so
//   this code usually closes the wrong tab.
var aTab = gBrowser.mTabs[gBrowser.getBrowserIndexForDocument(oPage)]
aTab.remove();
```

Any suggestions appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, i didnt test it. I also use `getWeakReference` so if your document is unloaded, it won't stay open in memory.

```
var arrPages = [];

//Open the tab
newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(gBrowser.addTab(inURL));
newTabBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", DOMloadedFunction, true);

// DOMContentLoaded eventhandler
DOMloadedFunction: function(event) {
    // store the tab
    arrPages.push(Cu.getWeakReference(event.target));
}

// Later the array is processed...
oPage = arrPages.shift();
var contDoc = oPage.get();
if (contDoc) { //test if tab is still open
    contDoc < --Do some stuff with DOM object.
}

// Now close the tab
oPage.close() // this is what I want to do, but I can't figure out how
var DOMWin = contDoc.defaultView.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
    .rootTreeItem
    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

if (DOMWin.gBrowser) {
    if (DOMWin.gBrowser.tabContainer) {
        DOMWin.gBrowser.removeTab(DOMWin.gBrowser.getTabForContentWindow(contDoc.defaultView));
    } else {
        DOMWin.close(); //no tabs probably a popup window of some kind
    }
} else {
    DOMWin.close(); //close window as its probably a popup window of some kind with no tabs
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this Noitidart.
Now I get to really show how much more I need to learn!...

I got it working, but had to prefix with an underscore:
...(DOMWin.gBrowser._getTabForContentWindow(...
I found that in another of your posts here:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421077/firefox-add-on-sdk-getting-the-tab-id)